# When is chapter 738 of the manga coming out?

Tags: one-piece, manga-production

In the last page of Chapter 737 of One Piece, it's stated that.

> The series will take a break next issue. It will start in WJ #13

What does this mean?

Comment: which chapter are you refering too as latest?

Comment: WJ #13 refers to Weekly Shōnen Jump issue 13. So week 13's shounen jump

Comment: @Robin I am talking about 737

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's exactly as it states. The manga is on break in the *next issue* (the one that comes out the week after chapter 737) (WJ#12). One-Piece will continue the following week (WJ#13), .

Answer (score 2):

Next chapter (738) will be out on February 18th. Scans will probably be up later that day or by early morning of Wednesday the 19th.